# markdown with png created with maven site plugin

Tags: maven, markdown, png, maven-site-plugin

I started to create my sites (via maven site plugin)
with source written in markdown.
I like a lot.
The MD files are placed in a separate folder
`markdown` in `src/site/`.

When creating the MD files I always check the links.
Links are between MD files and may also lead to other files like PNG, or PDF.
The other files are in folder `resources` in `src/site/`.

I found out that for links between md files I can use the file ending `md` and that the site plugin version `4.0.0-M9` transforms this into according `html`.
Since I write all my links relative, the links work in the MD sources and in the generated HTML files.

A problem arises if I try to link resources from within MD files.
Currently, I copy resources with the resources plugin.
To work in the sources I must write something like

```
![Home Screen](../resources/FER/01_homeScreen.png)
```

where the `..` comes from leaving the `markdown` folder, whereas in the target
the `markdown` folder disappears
and also the `resources` folder.
Thus, in the target the correct link must be

```
![Home Screen](./FER/01_homeScreen.png)
```

How to resolve this??
If no one knows, I have the idea to write a feature request for the site plugin.